# ngChange doesn't work for kendo-date-picker which defined in kendo.toolbarOptions

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, angularjs-ng-change, kendo-datepicker

I want to bind ngChange event to kendo-date-picker, the date picker defined in the toolbarOptions, but the ngChange doesn't work.

```js
 $scope.toolbarOptions = {
        items: [{
            template: "<label>From</label>"
        }, {
            template: "<input id='start' kendo-date-picker ng-model='dateString' k-ng-model='dateObject' ngChange='startChange()' />",
            overflow: "never"
        }]};

 $scope.startChange = function() {console.log('changed');}
 
 function startChange() {console.log('changed');}
```

please check my code, both of the startChange will not work. There's a ReferenceError: startChange is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You are using ngChange, Please change it with ng-change like:-

```
$scope.toolbarOptions = {
    items: [{
        template: "<label>From</label>"
    }, {
        template: "<input id='start' kendo-date-picker ng-model='dateString' k-ng-model='dateObject' ng-change='startChange()' />",
        overflow: "never"
    }]};

    $scope.startChange = function() {console.log('changed');}
```

or if you want to call javascript function then you have to define your js function before it using

```
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

        $scope.toolbarOptions = {
          items: [{
             template: "<label>From</label>"
            }, {
            template: "<input id='start' handle-change kendo-date-picker ng-model='dateString' k-ng-model='dateObject' onChange='startChange()' />",
        overflow: "never"
          }]

        };
    }).directive('handleChange',function(){
    return{
       link:function(scope,ele,attr){
         //you can use this
            //ele.on('change',function(){
              //alert(555)
           //})
      //or
      function startChange() {console.log('changed');}
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: tried your second solution, still throw an exception startChange is not defined

Comment: you can try new updated code , add "handle-change" directive

Comment: thanks for your reply. My controller is very big and there's lots of other items in the toolbarOptions, is there an elegant way?

Comment: You can use this directive in your parent div like <div class="demo-section k-content wide" ng-controller="MyCtrl" handle-change>
    <div kendo-toolbar k-options="toolbarOptions"></div>
  </div>